# Shadows and grease pencil have disappeared

Tags: grease-pencil, shadows

I'm having problems in this image. When I started creating it, there were cast shadows under the cloud in the foreground, and the Zeppelin. There are also supposed to be spinning propellers on each of the engines, but somewhere along the way they both disappeared. I've tried re-appending the Zeppelin from a file in which the grease pencil is visible, but it disappears once appended to this file. [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xxDWfCDaNSSjnRa0IptwydO7jB2Bl29/view?usp=sharing) Does anyone have any suggestions to get shadows to get those elements back?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without the blend file, it's unlikely for someone here to track down the issue. Please upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com/